# Heroku bot goes offline when deploying discord.js bot

Tags: discord, bots

I've created a discord bot and i'm using Heroku to host it. Everything was working until i programmed my bot to join vocal chats and play audios. From that moment when i deploy the bot it stays offline. It doesn't show any

Answer (score 0):

Personally haven't done anything voice related, a possible source of problems is permissions which you might need to check out (on the discord Developer Portal) and then integrate it properly in your code using the constructor of intents(passing as a parameter a number generated by the Portal when you insert your needed permissions).[example from my code regarding the intent part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjWJK.png)